# how to email a summary of commits in a repo daily

Tags: git, email, hook

I am still learning about git and i have looked at git hooks and how they work. Git can send an email for each git push using the post-receive hook, but i wanted to know if there is a way to have a daily messages or history email opposed to one for each commit.

thank you guys for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Daily" sounds like a good fit for a job scheduler like "cron."  Just write a script that asks git the current revision number, does a `git log` from the last one until current, and then write the current revision down as the last one (so the next run doesn't duplicate messages).

No need for git hooks this way...though if you really really wanted to you could make a hook that writes each commit message into a dated file somewhere, and whenever it is invoked on a "new" day, email out the previous day's file and delete it.

Comment: something like this? 

http://thejaswi.info/tech/blog/2010/11/01/summarize-commits-for-the-day/

Comment: http://codemonkeytips.blogspot.com/2010/01/daily-commit-logs-batching-git-commit.html MUCH BETTER :D